# Row security policy & partitions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, postgres-10

A PostgreSQL 10.6 table has row security policy enabled on a field, say `id`. The table has multiple partitions based on `id`.

Before executing a select query, the value for the field was set using the `SET` statement.

But when the select query is run, I see from the explain plan that PostgreSQL has to scan through all partitions to find the right partition corresponding to the value that was set using the `SET` statement.

Whereas if the `id` was passed in the `WHERE` clause, it picked the right partition without scanning through them all.

Is there a way to make a row security policy pick the correct partition similar to the where clause?

Answer (score 3):

If your policy depends on a parameter being set, you probably use `current_setting()` to retrieve it.

Since the value is not known when the query is parsed, PostgreSQL v10 cannot apply *partition pruning*.

Depending on your query, upgrading to v11 may help, because this version has added support for partition pruning at query execution time.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. Will try upgrading to v11